# Scale does not work with includegraphics

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I've seen this question asked, but I have not seen an answer that works for me.

I am trying to include screenshots from my program with includegraphics.  I have many screenshots -- all of different pixel widths.  I would like to be able to include them at the same 'scale' such that text in each remains the same size.

Long ago, I was able to do this with the [scale=0.75] option for includegraphics.  This no longer works as it seems includegraphics now ignores the dpi information stored in the PNG file.

The PNG starts at 72dpi (I have changed it in an image editor to 300dpi, no change) and including it with scale=1.0, 0.5, and 0.1 all give identical results -- the image does not scale.

Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[]{aiaa-tc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{example-image.png}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image.png}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I am running TeXShop on a Mac using pdftex.

[image: sample image]

Changing the first few lines...

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

remedies the problem.  Of course, I am submitting an AIAA paper, so it would be best to find a solution that works with this class file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which TeX distribution you employ, and please provide a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: `\includegraphics` basically is just a wrapper to the back end driver so the code for say pdftex is completely different to that in xetex or luatex, so it never ignores a scale option it simply passes it on to the back end as a request to scale, but you have given no information about which system you are using.

Comment: please show a complete example, if possible using `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image.png}` as that file is generally available for tests.

Comment: When working on producing a MWE, I found that the problem is somehow caused by the aiaa-tc class.  Switching to article and explicitly usepackage graphicx seems to work.

Comment: if you had used `example-image` rather than `image` people would have been able to run the example and seen the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed that subtlety in your comment.  I was a bit concerned that it was something with my PNG file, so I wanted to include one anyway.  I noticed that stackexchange clobbered the file name anyway, so people would need to rename a file when downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you are using does

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
```

so all images are unconditionally scaled as large as possible to fit in the text block.

This is clearly an intentional choice of the publisher so if you are using a journal that mandates this class, that is just the way it is.

So `scale` is more or less disabled, but you can re-specify `width` to scale the image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{aiaa-tc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding that.

Hard to see how it is intentional while still allowing you to set width=foo.  It seems like a misguided idea to me.

I am submitting a conference paper -- with no review of formatting.  It should look the part, but nobody will be particularly picky.

I'll remove that line from the class file and everything should work from there.

Thanks

Comment: @user52485 yes it is a bit odd, but the main takeaway since my name is on the graphicx package is **it's not my fault** You could raise it with the class maintainers